# Autofac - Prevent "manual" instantiation of a class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a class that I want Autofac to be the only one that can resolve an instance of.

**I want to make it so `new()`'ing the class in plain C# code won't work** (either at compile time or at runtime).

The class does not take any dependencies.

**How can I achieve that?** I tried using a `private` constructor. It helps preventing `new()` at compile time but Autofac is not able to use reflection to instantiate it and fails.

An awkward option might be to artificially add a dependency via the class constructor's parameter, which will implicitly tell developers that `new()` is going to be hard and probably refrain from doing it by accident, but it's far from ideal since:

1. They would still be technically able to instantiate (I admin that this argument is valid for all other plain DI-enabled classes as well...)
2. It smells to add a parameter just because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor for the class, you can walk the calling stack until you find a call going to AutoFac's `Resolve` method.  If it is not found, err out.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private void AssertAutoFac()
    {
        var trace = new StackTrace();
        for (int i=2; i<trace.FrameCount; i++)  //Start with i=2, skipping last two stack entries, which will be internal to this class anyway
        { 
            var method = trace.GetFrame(i).GetMethod();
            if (method.Name == "Resolve") 
            {
                var dll = method.DeclaringType.Assembly.FullName;
                if (dll == "Autofac, Version=1.4.4.561, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da") return;  
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You must instantiate using AutoFac!");
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        AssertAutoFac();
    }
}
```

**=== EDIT BY THE OP ===**

The above works great. A shorter version of it might be:

```
var autofacInstantiated = trace.GetFrames().Skip(2).Any(t=> t.GetMethod().DeclaringType != null && t.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace.StartsWith("Autofac"));
    if (!autofacInstantiated)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You must instantiate using AutoFac!");
```

With the caveat that it won't check for a very specific Autofac assembly, thus, in theory, one could forged a method within a (fake) `Autofac.*` namespace and fool this mechanism. But if all you want is sanity protection against accidental manual instantiations by future developers, this does the trick.

Also this one is tolerant to Autofac version updates (the first code snippet can be amended accordingly as well, though).

Comment: Bam! Nice trick! I managed to narrow it down to a short LINQ expression. Mine doesn't check for a hard & specific assembly though (which I could add but that would just make the LINQ expression longer) but unless someone fakes an Autofac root namespace, it should be good.

I'm updating your answer to provide the shorter form as well. Otherwise, thanks very much!

Comment: This might work but is probably not the best solution. The `UsingConstructor` mechanism in Autofac would probably be better and allow you to use a private constructor by specifying it. Also, given reflection is different in .NET and .NET Core, this probably won't work in .NET Core.

Comment: Correction - the constructor selection mechanisms in Autofac, not specifically the `UsingConstructor` method. Point being, I wouldn't rely on stack traces here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really stop someone from invoking the constructor at runtime since reflection allows this.

I'm really not sure why you want to keep the constructor private. It outlines some other problem, in my opinion, but to answer your question, here's how you can do it. Given the following class definition:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

You can register it this way in Autofac:

```cs
var privateMyClassConstructor = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    Type.EmptyTypes,
    null);

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder
    .Register(x => (MyClass)privateMyClassConstructor.Invoke(null))
    .AsSelf();

var container = builder.Build();

var firstMyClassInstance = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
var secondMyClassInstance = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

I'd recommend keeping the discovery of the constructor via reflection outside of the registration since it's supposedly quite slow and you want to do this only once.

Comment: Nice one @Mickaël !

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
[Obsolete("This constructor is for Autofac only")]
public MyConstructor()
{
}
```

It will generate a warning if anyone calls it explicitly, but Autofac will still use the constructor. Hopefully warnings are just as intolerable as errors in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the classes of interest are in a library and not in your main program, you can use attributes to control scope.

1. Keep the class `public`
2. Make all constructors `internal`.
3. In order to get AutoFac to be able to call the internal constructors, use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to enable AutoFac to access them.

   ```
   //Expose all internal members to AutoFac
   [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Autofac")]
   public class MyClass
   {
       internal MyClass()
       {
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The classes are actually within the same assembly that's accessing them (not the main program but still, same assembly). Pulling them out just for this protection is something I'd rather not do. Will go with your 2nd answer :)

Comment: You'll need to use Autofac's fully qualified name (including public key) for this to work.